# Yaml strategy ignores MSTest Class Parallelization

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, automated-tests, mstest, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have MSTest Framework with set up parallelization in Class Level. Meaning, tests within classes are running sequentially. Tests from different classes can be run in parallel.

```
[assembly: Parallelize(Workers = 0, Scope = ExecutionScope.ClassLevel)]
```

These Tests are running on ADO yaml pipeline with strategy enabled.

```
  - job: UITestsRun
    strategy:
      parallel: 10
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - download: ${{parameters.TestDllArtifactName}}
    - task: VSTest@2
      inputs:
        testAssemblyVer2: '**\Automation.Tests.dll'
        searchFolder: 'TestDllPath'
        resultsFolder: 'TestResults'
        testFiltercriteria: '${{parameters.AdditionalTestCriterias}}'
        runSettingsFile: 'testsettings.runsettings'
        publishRunAttachments: true
        batchingBasedOnAgentsOption: customBatchSize
        customBatchSizeValue: 10
        rerunFailedTests: true
        rerunFailedThreshold: 100
        rerunMaxAttempts: 1
```

What has been noticed is that tests from the same class can be run at the same time at different jobs (agents).

E.g., Job**1** is running **ClassA**.Test1 while Job**2** is running **ClassA**.Test2.

This causing a lot of failures because tests are not designed this way.

We would like tests to be running in parallel jobs when class level parallelization is also taken into account.
Does anyone know if there is a way to do that?

Comment: Unit Tests should be atomic, and this is a hot trend where builds are done by multiple instances/agents. Can you force all Tests in a class to be handled by one agent if you use a `[SetUp]` and `[TearDown]`, even if they assert.True() to try and trick it? OR can you try decorating the tests with `[DoNotParallelize]`? Alternatively write them atomically so they're independent of one and other.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, Unfortenetelly it's a functional UI tests on complex app which are hard (read imposible) to make atomic.
We need to run tests in parallel but on;y on class level. [DoNotParallelize] will prevent it. Which will cause huge increase in execution time.
I'm not sure I got your suggestion on Setup TearDown. We do have those in use for tests to setup some common data/settings. How can it be used to force tests to be run at the same agent?

Comment: Right you're doing End 2 End (e2e) testing. If you "Bind" all your Winform controls to a business logic layer using Binding Controls then you abstract the GUI from the logic - that way you only need to have tests for the business logic! WRT the E2E test and FatClients there's a few tools to get the "Selenium" behaviour: SikuliX is free, simply watch the youtube vids. With code I'd probably switch over to Nunit and use the `[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]` and wrap the Test classes with `[TestFixture]`

Comment: Unfortenetelly NUnit make no diffrence, even though all attributes are on the place, pipeline jobs will still ignore it

Answer (score 1):

By default, the [**VSTest@2 task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vstest-v2?view=azure-pipelines) applies '**`basedOnTestCases`**' (**Based on number of tests and agents**) as the batch test slicing method. This method divides up the tests simply based on the number of tests and agents participating in the test run. So, this may divide up the tests from the same test assembly into different parallel jobs to run.

For your case, you can try to select '**`basedOnAssembly`**' (**Based on test assemblies**) method. This method divides up the tests from the same test assembly together into a same parallel job to run. And the tests in the same test assembly run sequentially.

[image]

For more details, you can see "[**Set up parallel testing (VSTest) - Test slicing**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/parallel-testing-vstest?view=azure-devops#test-slicing)".

Comment: OP to control this with finer granularity you can further split tests into different projects.

Comment: Currecntly we have 100+ test classes. So if to move each class under new project it will be 100+ project. Does not seems like a maintanable solution :(

Comment: @OxanaViktorovna, Just go to try the '**`basedOnAssembly`**' method on **VSTest@2 task** in your pipeline.

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT I've performed the run with basedOnAssembly. It's not working for us. It's running all tests within same job. So there is no parallelization agent whise

Comment: @OxanaViktorovna, Looks like, you have only one test assembly.

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT that's correct. And with 100+ test class it will impossible to split each to separate assembly

Comment: @OxanaViktorovna, if all the tests are in the same assembly, I am afraid that it is not possible to meet your demands.